# Is it possible to block a specific query, or return a static result?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, myisam

Before you yell at me for doing it wrong, I know I'm doing it wrong. I'm using WHMCS (source code is not available), and we have a quarter of a million invoices. One particular query, which runs on every page, is absolutely murdering the database.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(amountin-amountout) 
FROM tblaccounts 
WHERE invoiceid IN (
                    SELECT 
                      id 
                    FROM tblinvoices 
                    WHERE 
                      userid=*userid* AND status='Unpaid'
                   )
```

This generates the logged-in user's total unpaid invoice sum. Problem is, due to the nested queries, each pageload is running over 450k queries (the amount of rows in `tblaccounts`), each of which is filtering over 750k rows (the amount of rows in `tblinvoices`).

Can this be blocked at the database server level? Or ideally, set to return a specific value?

Server version: 5.5.41-0+wheezy1-log - (Debian)
Protocol version: 10

The tables are using the MyISAM engine. Here are the CREATE TABLE statements:

#### tblaccounts

```
CREATE TABLE `tblaccounts` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `currency` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `gateway` text NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `amountin` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `fees` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `amountout` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `rate` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00000',
  `transid` text NOT NULL,
  `invoiceid` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `refundid` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `invoiceid` (`invoiceid`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `transid` (`transid`(32))
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

#### tblinvoices

```
CREATE TABLE `tblinvoices` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `invoicenum` text NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `duedate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `datepaid` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `subtotal` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `credit` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `tax` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `tax2` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `taxrate` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `taxrate2` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` text NOT NULL,
  `paymentmethod` text NOT NULL,
  `notes` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `status` (`status`(3)),
  KEY `userid-status` (`userid`,`status`(3))
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Ouch, MyISAM - and `status` is TEXT? Thats really bad as covering index cannot be used on TEXT column.. Does it really contain long texts or could you in reality transform it to a VARCHAR of some reasonable length without losing any data? It it were possible, then adding index on `(userid, status, id)` to `tblinvoices` should make it noticeably faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell the answer to this question is no.  You can't block this `SELECT` at the database level, or [rewrite it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriter-query-rewrite-plugin.html) in versions before 5.7.6 (dev milestone 16 for the 5.7 release).

If the offending statement were an `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE` then you could use the tactics described in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10301402/5190842) to nullify the statement via a trigger.

As established in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138098/5190842) (also on StackOverflow), you can't put a trigger on a `SELECT` statement.

Given the above is true, you will have to do one of three things:

1. Put a proxy like [MySQL Proxy](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) <sup>(that proxy was discovered by [Dr. McKay](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/56849/dr-mckay))</sup> between the database and the application that will replace the query and return a cached/static result as suggested by [jkavalik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/64556/jkavalik) initially.
2. Wait for your support ticket to work it's way through WHMCS's bug system.
3. Figure out how to optimize this query until it isn't a problem anymore or option 1/2 are in place.

We can't help with option 1 or 2, but we can help you optimize your query.  Optimizing the query may bring the execution time down from tenfold, which will lessen your organization's pain, and make you look like a hero.  I vote you take this route while you are waiting for the bug ticket if you can't install the proxy or get it working.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for the proxy suggestion. Still no response from WHMCS on the ticket. I can't say I'd recommend them at all after this!

Answer (score 2):

(Building on jkavalik's comment)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT status) AS diff_statuses,
       GROUP_CONCAT(status) AS statuses,
       MAX(LENGTH(status)) AS max_len
   FROM tblinvoices;
```

If there are only a few `diff_statuses`, then

```
ALTER TABLE tblinvoices
    MODIFY COLUMN status ENUM( ... ) NOT NULL,
    DROP INDEX status,
    DROP INDEX `userid-status`,
    ADD INDEX status (status),
    ADD INDEX `userid-status` (userid, status, id);
```

where `...` is statuses with quotes added around each.

If `diff_statuses` is big, then do a similar `ALTER`, but with this

```
    MODIFY COLUMN status VARCHAR( ... ) NOT NULL
```

where `...` is some value safely a bit above max_len.

The ENUM approach will shrink the table and index because ENUM will be 1 byte.

Prefix indexes are virtually useless.  Adding `id` makes the index "covering", hence perhaps twice as fast for the subquery.